# Image printing in asp.net MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, image, printing

I am trying out asp.net mvc and i learned how to retrieve and display image from database.

this is how i am displaying image in browser with the help of **HomeController** and **GetImage** method which takes **ID** as parameter its works fine.

*View code snippet*

```
<img alt="DRS IMAGE" src="@Url.Action("GetImage", "Home", new { ID })" />
```

How would I provide print button in view the, so when I click on that button it prints out display image on browser?

Comment: What exactly are you having difficulties with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to write a javascript function that will open a new window set to the image URL (as above).

Attach this function to the click event of a button and you are good to go.

Comment: Thank you oded. I appreciate your replay. All is well now. you are jam.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using jQuery there is a plugin called jqPrint which is good for sending contents of a div or other element to print, possibly a good solution.